# how to remove padding in struct python during unpacking

Tags: python-3.x, struct, byte, argument-unpacking

When I use packing in struct, I find out that during unpacking that I have extra characters after I unpack the byte object.

For example before packing:
`c = b'CONNECT'`
value gotten after unpacking using struct is `b'CONNECT\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'`

Here is my code:

```
import struct
import datetime
import binascii

string_format = '12s'
s = struct.Struct(string_format)
str = 'CONNECT'
byte = str.encode()
print(byte)

packed_data = s.pack(byte)
print(packed_data)
unpacked_data = s.unpack(packed_data)
unpacked_data = unpacked_data[0]
arr = []

for item in unpacked_data.decode():
    print(item)
    arr.append(item)

print(arr)
```

How can I get `b'CONNECT'` after unpacking.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: import struct
import datetime
import binascii


string_format = '12s'
s = struct.Struct(string_format)
str = 'CONNECT'
byte = str.encode()
print(byte)

packed_data = s.pack(byte)
print(packed_data)
unpacked_data = s.unpack(packed_data)
unpacked_data = unpacked_data[0]

arr = []
for item in unpacked_data.decode():
    print(item)
    arr.append(item)


print(arr)

Answer (score 0):

The additional `NUL` bytes are added because you update the struct format to have 12 characters with `'12s'`. If you add `print('CONNECT'.encode())` before all your statements, you'll see that it's correct.

Since you'll probably want to [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) off the additional characters, just use that function:

```
print(repr(unpacked_data.decode().strip()))          #Prints 'CONNECT'
```